# How to check time Zone in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to show the timezone in snowflake like "US/Pacific" or "GMT".
is there any function which can show that.
Something like 
select current_timezone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can run the following in your session:

```
show parameters like '%timezone%';
```

You can also see the current offset when you run the following:

```
select current_timestamp();
```